# Converting string "{a:2, b:4}" into object {a:2, b:4}

Tags: javascript

I wanted to convert this string `"{a:2, b:4}"` into Object `{a:2, b:4}`.

I tried `JSON.parse("{a:2, b:4}")` and got no result.

The real data I'm getting is a little complex and can't post here because of company data.

Is there any way in JS to achieve it.

Comment: The reason JSON.parse didn't work is because that is not JSON. If your string was `{"a":2, "b":4}`, then you could have used JSON.parse

Comment: Is there a way? Sure, you could always use `eval` (please don't tho). Otherwise you need to transform that into valid JSON somehow or parse it into an object manually.

Comment: Where does the data come from? Is it a user-provided object or is it something that you are building completely by yourself?

Comment: Thanks @AlbertoRivera for comment.. will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use `eval` function:

```
s = '{a:2, b:4}'
eval('('+s+')')
// returns {a:2, b:4}
```

Don't forget to put your object in `(...)`

Comment: This worked like this ``eval(`(${data})`)``

Comment: Security aside, this assumes that data follows the syntax of JavaScript code (something we don't know) and doesn't have structures that can trigger function calls.

Comment: Actually data is just simple plain object with multiple key & values<string>.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let parsedObject = JSON.parse('{"a":2, "b":4}')
console.log(parsedObject)
```

`JSON.parse('{"a":2, "b":4}')` would work.

Comment: How do you convert the original data into JSON?

Comment: This will work.. thanks but I'm getting data in `"{a:2, b:4}"` format and real data is little complex, can't change data like above. But I'll try it out once..

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a reliable parser unless you know the syntax of the format but, for the simple test case you've shared, you could do something like this (error checking omitted for brevity):

```js
const input = '{a:2, b:4}';
const parsed = input.match(/^\{([a-z]+):(\d+),\s*([a-z]+):(\d+)\}$/);
const output = {
  [parsed[1]]: parsed[2],
  [parsed[3]]: parsed[4]
}
console.log(output, typeof output);
```

Comment: With real complex data, this method is not convenient, I guess

Comment: Absolutely not. However, the issue wouldn't really be complexity but variability. What *else* can data contain?